# Spring Boot and multiple databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've setup a basic spring project with a single database connection.

In the application.properties file I have the database settings:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.19/ticket
spring.datasource.username = dbusername
spring.datasource.password = dbpassword
```

I've created a base DAO class which other DAOs extend:

```java
@Transactional
public class Dao<E> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<E> entityClass;

    public Dao(Class<E> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public void create(E object) {
        entityManager.persist(object);

        return;
    }

    public void delete(E object) {
        if (entityManager.contains(object)) {
            entityManager.remove(object);
        } else {
            entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(object));
        }

        return;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<E> getAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from " + entityClass.getName()).getResultList();
    }

    public E get(long id) {
        return entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public void update(E object) {
        entityManager.merge(object);
        return;
    }
}
```

Here's a sample entity that extends the base DAO:

```java
@Repository
public class PersonDao extends Dao<Person> {

    public PersonDao() {
        super(Person.class);
    }
}
```

Currently this uses a single database, but I need to be able to add a second database, and somehow define in each DAO which datasource to use. Each DAO will only use a single database, so there's no requirement for a DAO to be able to connect to multiple databases.

I've done some research, and that seems to suggest I need to use `JdbcTemplate`? but I can't seem to find a tutorial that matches my need. Also, at the minute the entityManager is injected into the DAO, but the `JdbcTemplate` examples I've looked at don't seem to use the entityManager, which is slightly confusing.

Comment: Since you're starting with Spring, take a look at Spring Data repositories; they'll basically generate your entire DAO class for you, plus automatically build most simple queries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

```html
database.password1=<password1>
database.url1=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/twodbone
database.username1=<username1>
database.password2=<password1>
database.url2=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/twodbtwo
database.username2=<username2>
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

In this way you can add the multiple databases and configure both hibernate.cfg.xml file and applicationContext.xml file also..

Comment: my project doesn't have a hibernate.cfg.xml or applicationcontext.xml file as I'm using springboot which handles most of this for me I believe.

Comment: go through this link http://xantorohara.blogspot.in/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html

Comment: how will that work when the repository extends CrudRepository and makes use of findOne(), save() methods? How will the CrudRepository know to use the jdbcTemplate and not the entityManager? I think this is where I'm getting confused as the example link doesn't mention the use of CrudRepository, but seems to make it's own queries on the database.

Answer (score 0):

```html
@Repository
public class FooRepository
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void saveFoo(Foo foo)
    {
         this.entityManager.persist(foo);
    }

    public List<SomeReportPojo> getSomeReport()
    {
         return this.entityManager.queryForList("SELECT .. ",SomeProjectPojo.class); 
    }
}
```

this.jdbcTemplate should be kept rather than this.entityManager for jdbc templetes

this is simple example

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure I understand. Are you saying keep using the EntityManager for the current database connection, and use a JdbcTemplate for the 2nd connection? How will the spring/hibernate ORM with with the JDBC template?